# Trying to loop through multiple URLs and import some data rom each

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to hack together code that loops through a few URLs and grabs a few data points from each URL. Here is my super-hackey code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=mountain+bikes&ref=nb_sb_noss_"
current_page = 1

while current_page < 5:
    print(current_page)
    url = base_url + str(current_page)
    #current_page += 1
    r = requests.get(url)
    zute_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    firme = zute_soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'brand-follow-tooltip-root'})
    
    title = []
    desc = []
    page = []
    for title in firme:
        title1 = title.findAll('h1')[0].text
        print(title1)
        adresa = title.findAll('div', {'class': 'brand-follow-tooltip-root'})[0].text
        print(adresa)
        print('\n')
        page_line = "{title1}\n{adresa}".format(
            title1=title1,
            adresa=adresa
        )
        
        title.append(title1)
        desc.append(adresa)
        page.append(page_line)
    current_page += 1
```

The code finishes in a few seconds and I get no errors, but nothing in appended to any of the lists. I think this is close, but I don't what what the issue is here.

Answer (score 0):

For every iteration you are nullying them, is this expected ?

```py
while current_page < 5:
    
  .
  .
  .
    title = []
    desc = []
    page = []
.
.
.
        title.append(title1)
        desc.append(adresa)
        page.append(page_line)
    current_page += 1
```

Move

```
    title = []
    desc = []
    page = []
```

out of while loop. And your appendeds wont be nullified.

Comment: Good catch! Not sure why I didn't see that. I made the change and the result is still the same; no results.  I think the problem is here: title1 = title.findAll('h1')[0].text
Also, there seems to be a problem here: adresa = title.findAll('div', {'class': 'brand-follow-tooltip-root'})[0].text